# chaining recursive promise with bluebird

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, bluebird

I have a promise chain with a recursive promise doAsyncRecursive() in the middle like so:

```
doAsync().then(function() {
    return doAsyncRecursive();
}).then(function() {
    return doSomethingElseAsync();
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

`doAsyncRecursive()` has to do something and if it at first does not succeed, i then after want to try every 5 seconds until it does. This is what my promise function looks like:

```
function doAsyncRecursive() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //do async thing
        if (success) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    doAsyncRecursive();
                }, 5000);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But when I execute, the chain does not continue after `doAsyncRecursive()` is successful on the 2nd try and `resolve()` is called (it continues if the attempt is successful on the 1st try however).

What pattern do I need to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Catch the failure, wait five seconds, then try again.

```
function doAsyncRecursive() {
    return doAsyncThing().catch(function() {
        return Promise.delay(5000).then(doAsyncRecursive);
    });
}
```

Here `doAsyncThing` is a function corresponding to the `//do async thing` comment in the OP's code, defined as returning a promise. In the original code, the success or failure of the "do async thing" is tested using a `success` flag, but by definition asynchronous routines do not deliver such a flag; they deliver their results either via a callback or a promise. The code above assumes that `doAsyncThing` returns a promise. It also assumes that "failure", in the sense of "does not return the response i want", is represented by that promise rejecting. If instead "success" or "failure" is to be defined as some particular value of a fulfilled promise, then you'd want to do

```
function doAsyncRecursive() {
    return doAsyncThing().then(function(success) {
        if (success) return success;
        else return Promise.delay(5000).then(doAsyncRecursive);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry but i am having trouble understanding this solution as I dont know what you mean by the async() call. maybe i wasnt clear - doAsync() and doAsyncRecursive() are completely different functions doing different asynchronous tasks, and doAsyncRecursive() is just trying to call doAsyncRecursive() over and over again when it does not return the response i want. was this your understanding as well?

Comment: thanks for the update. i modified my code to reject my promise based on a test condition and made a similar wrapper function that returns my async promise like you suggested, and it works now! i see now how everything falls through to return a promise so the chain can continue. cheers :)

Comment: This solution leaks memory on every `catch()`.

Comment: @kikap Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @torazaburo I've found your answer when trying to figure out why my memory usage slowly grows with each request. I'm using a very similar method to restart a blocking-promise-returning function, and I know that according to the Promise spec the recursive call made from `.then` handler doesn't grow the stack. But in my implementation (measured with `process.memoryUsage()` with `--expose-gc`  parameter to `node` and `gc();` calls in the program) I observe a slow constant growth of used memory. I'm using bluebird.

Comment: @kikap That's interesting. Is there any chance you could try with native promises or another promises implementation? Is this something you maybe should report as a bug against Bluebird?