# Recursive Promise in Bluebird not returning

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I've read 
[Produce a promise which depends on recursive promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650204/produce-a-promise-which-depends-on-recursive-promises)
[chaining recursive promise with bluebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938737/chaining-recursive-promise-with-bluebird)
[Recursive Promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144707/recursive-promises)
but I still can't figure out what's wrong with how I'm structuring my promises

So I'm fetching objects from a database. Every object has a field, but sometimes it has a reference to a UUID. So for example, if a person has a friend and mother, it would be like

```
{
   "id": e872530a-27fc-4263-ad39-9a21568c31ef,
   "name": "dood",
   "friendId": "571746fc-686d-4170-a53e-7b7daca62fa0",
   "motherId": "99b65849-1f1c-4881-a1d0-c5ae432e83a2"
}
```

Now, the idea is when I fetch an object I want to replace any other UUID's with the expanded version.

```
{
   "id": e872530a-27fc-4263-ad39-9a21568c31ef,
   "name": "dood",
   "friendId": {
      "id": "571746fc-686d-4170-a53e-7b7daca62fa0",
      "name": "peter"
   },
   "motherId": {
      "id": "99b65849-1f1c-4881-a1d0-c5ae432e83a2",
      "name": "ma"
   }
}
```

Thus, I'm using promises and recursion to try this but I can't figure out what's going wrong in my promises. I get this result instead

```
{
   "id": e872530a-27fc-4263-ad39-9a21568c31ef,
   "name": "dood",
   "friendId": {
      "isFulfilled": False,
      "isRejected": False
   },
   "motherId": {
      "isFulfilled": False,
      "isRejected": False
   }
}
```

I've using bluebird js, and here is how the code looks like

```
function getExpandedObj(uuid, recursiveLevel) {
    return getObj(uuid) //This gets the object from the database
        .then(function(obj) {
           //I convert the obj to an array where each element is
           //{property:value} so I can do a map over it
           // some code to do that, I think it's irrelevant so I'll 
           // skip it
           return objArr;
        })
        .map(function(obj) {
            //prevent infinite recursion
            if (recursiveLevel > 0) {
               for (var property in obj) {
                   if (typeof(obj[property]) === "string" ) {
                       var uuid = obj[property].match(/(\w{8}(-\w{4}){3}-\w{12}?)/g);
                       if (uuid != null) {
                          uuid = uuid[0];
                          obj[property] = getExpandedObj(uuid, recursiveLevel-1)
                              .then(function(exObj) { return exObj;})
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
        })
        .then(function(obj) {return obj;})
}
```

Comment: Ah, so that is what [you were asking for previously](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32193946/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a) your mapping function does `return` nothing so it is not awaited b) you shouldn't use `map` here at all.

The perfect solution for this is Bluebird's [`Promise.props`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html) which awaits the promises on an object's properties.

```
function getUuid(value) {
     if (typeof value != "string") return null;
     var uuid = value.match(/\w{8}(-\w{4}){3}-\w{12}?/);
     if (uuid) return uuid[0];
     return null;
}
function getExpandedObj(uuid, recursiveLevel) {
    return getObj(uuid).then(function(obj) {
        // prevent infinite recursion
        if (recursiveLevel <= 0)
            return obj;
        for (var property in obj) {
            var uuid = getUuid(obj[property])
            if (uuid) {
                obj[property] = getExpandedObj(uuid, recursiveLevel-1);
            }
        }
        return Promise.props(obj);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
obj[property] = getExpandedObj(uuid, recursiveLevel-1)
   .then(function(exObj) {
     return exObj;
   });
```

to

```
return getExpandedObj(uuid, recursiveLevel-1)
 .then(function(exObj) {
    obj[property] = exObj;
    return obj;
});
```

because you were setting the value to be the promise object instead of the actual value.